# Add custom error messages to CI validation_errors()

Tags: php, codeigniter

There's a way to add custom error messages to CodeIgniter `validation_errors();`?

Example, if I wanted a field with a `123456` value, and the user inputs `12345` I'd want to set a message to say:

> *The number 6 is required!*

And any other custom rules I may want to add. Like a specific pattern or any other things.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

Set rules with callback like,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Number', 'callback_custom_validation');
```

and define callback in the same controller like,

```
public function custom_validation($str)
{
    if ($str != '123456')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('field_name', 'The %s field requires 123456');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Display your errors in view with `<?php echo form_error('field_name')?>`

More info on callbacks [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Comment: I think the first argument of set_message() should be the name of the callback function. $this->form_validation->set_message('custom_validation', 'The %s field requires 123456');